Maven Assembly Plugin add additional folder previous to the output directory
I am using maven-assembly-plugin to copy the different dependencies of a single project to different folders. Meaning, each dependency of the project need to be copied, with it's dependencies, to a specific folder. I chose maven-assembly-plugin because of useTransitiveDependencies option.
here is my pom :

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>deps-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                  <attach>false</attach>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>


and here is my assembly
<assembly ...>
    <id>deps-assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>
                    dep1-groupid:dep1-artifactid
                </include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>dep1</outputDirectory>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>
                    dep2-groupid:dep2-artifactid
                </include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>dep2</outputDirectory>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets> </assembly>

Problem is, the assembly plugin is creating an additional directory named Artifact-Version then put my both folders. Meaning instead of having :
MyArtifact/dependencies/dep1 and MyArtifact/dependencies/dep2
I have
MyArtifact/dependencies/MyArtifact-1.0/dep1 and MyArtifact/dependencies/MyArtifact-1.0/dep2
do you know how I can get the needed path please ?

Why are you copying files to a different directory?

I work on a big multiservices product that have it's own runtime and classpath management system. The goal is to migrate it from ant to maven without interfering with the runtime, so need to re-construct same existing structure
